# Is "clean the chicken" an old expression?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning

In a letter written in 1897 my grandfather, who was hiking cross country, said he was only going to eat 2 meals a day and "clean the chicken".  Was this an expression and what did it mean?  Or am I just misreading his handwriting?

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: Additional context might help. What are the surrounding sentences?

Comment: Probably means "clean the bones": Eat the remaining meat clinging to the chicken bones. (Clean the meat off the bones.)